# Google Sheets - Combine VLOOKUP with Named Ranges to create Drop Down

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have 3 worksheets - *Stocks*, *Products*, and *Sizes*.

I have created 3 named ranges:
'Adults', 'Kids' and 'Shoes'.

On the *Stock* worksheet, once a product has been added - I'd like the size column to become a drop down containing the correct sizes for that product - based on the named range set in *Products*.

**EXAMPLE**

Product 'redshirt1' in *Products* has been assigned a range of 'Adults'.
Therefore, the following cell in *Stock* should contain a drop down with the following sizes: L, XL, XXL

[image]

I hope that's clear enough, thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bxmItQpOOQ-WTBsd0uA0WmzYACVUdtCVRaex879KgcE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
      validationManagement(sh,sh.getRange(i,j))
    }
  }
}
function validationManagement(sh,cel){
  if (sh.getName()=='Pending' && cel.getRow()>1 && cel.getColumn()==10){
    if (cel.getValue()==''){
      cel.offset(0, 2).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    }else{
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var styles = ss.getSheetByName('Styles').getDataRange().getValues().filter( r => (r[0]==cel.getValue()) )
      var sizes = ss.getSheetByName('Sizes')
      var col = sizes.getRange(1,1,1,sizes.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().indexOf(styles[0][2])+1
      cel.offset(0, 2).clearContent().clearDataValidations(); 
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sizes.getRange(2,col,sizes.getLastRow()-1,1)).build()
      cel.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}
```

This will allow you to change multiple values at once.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfs3fIj8pgMkmfySzbXUCqgXainG2o1rchLg4foVZeo/edit?usp=sharing

### references

- [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)

Comment: This is great Mike I really appreciate it. I've just noticed a small bug when adding multiple products at once. It seems to set all products to the first size range found. In this example you can see that mens size work individually, womens size work individually, but when you paste both men and women codes together - it shows men for all the items including womens. https://streamable.com/jvn5zf

Comment: Ok, it's not exactly a bug, onEdit is only available when you change one cell at a time ... I will update soon to allow you to change multiple cells. Let me one hour or two ...

Comment: Thank you Mike for clarifying that and I am grateful for your efforts. Also I may want to remove the size name (eg Nike M) from the actual drop down that's generated so if you could let me know which line to change. I'm sure that it's a matter of changing one of the 0s to a 1, but not sure which.

Comment: ok, I will also remove the size name

Comment: Try the new version and let me know if it is ok or if you need and modification!

Comment: Hi Mike, it's definitely fixed now but the function seems to stop at random points as it moves down the column and not all sizes get added: https://snipboard.io/4cZoBn.jpg Can you see the reason it's stopping? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfs3fIj8pgMkmfySzbXUCqgXainG2o1rchLg4foVZeo/edit?usp=sharing To re-test simply delete and re-paste those new style codes and you'll see what happens.

Comment: There is no reason except the time allowed by google to run a script ... I will optimize a little and try again. Let me one hour or two

Comment: Hi Mike, in that case I'm happy to just paste 10 at once. If you still want to optimise please go ahead but I don't mind working within the scripting timers.

Comment: I change a little, it's a bit faster but limit the number of changes at once, there is no much faster solution except if i am wrong

Comment: Thanks Mike it looks great. Once last thing on this question from me... I have another function which allows the user to choose a website, this brings up a drop down where they choose an email, and then it places the name linked to that email in Profiles. The problem I'm having is trying to have both functions run at the same time. I've tried to rename your function 'addSizes', and then run both functions under a nested OnEdit fucntion but neither are working. Could you please take a look: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfs3fIj8pgMkmfySzbXUCqgXainG2o1rchLg4foVZeo/edit#gid=0

Comment: Try the modifications, put a trigger on onSpeEdit if not already done. Let me know if it is ok!

Comment: Nice one Mike :) Both functions working as they should. Really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Hi Mike, I moved the code over to my main sheet (same layout and column/sheet names) and it didn't work. I then made a duplicate of SIZE PUBLIC 1.0 - and it didn't work on the duplicate either. It seems to only work on that original version - even though the AppScript is the same. Am I missing something here? Can you please make a duplicate of SIZE PUBLIC 1.0 and check if it works? Thanks. This is the 'Copy' I made and it's not working: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jWGI8waZmVOTZCtffDHmzDhz6lC9J3E55yjSUtheuVI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: do you put a trigger on onSpeEdit function ? click on the clock on the left hand side of the script editor, and add a trigger when something is modified

Comment: Legend. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The following formula would also return the correct Named Range according to the Range defined in Products:

`=INDIRECT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,Products!A2:Z,4, FALSE), ""))`

However, Data Validation lists in Google Sheets don't accept formulas as input.
In order to avoid having to create a "Helper column" for each row in Stock to populate the drop-down list, using Apps Scripts, you can achieve that with the [Simple Trigger onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to populate the Sizes column depending on the selected "Code".

#### Sample code (edit):

```js
function onEdit(){
  //This method runs every time a cell is modified
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var activeCell = ws.getActiveCell();

  if (activeCell.getColumn() == 10 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ws.getSheetName() == "Pending") { //Only runs if the value changed is on the "J" column of Pending except first row
    var wsStyles = ss.getSheetByName("Styles");
    var selectedValue = activeCell.getValue();

    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearContent().clearDataValidations().setValue("Loading...");

    //Get style Range column from Styles based on Code
    var styles = wsStyles.getDataRange().getValues();
    var rangeStyle = "";

    for (row of styles) { //looping through Styles and storing Range value in rangeStyle
      if (row[0] == selectedValue) {
        //Slightly edit here, since the Size name defined in Styles contains spaces, which Named Ranges doesn't accept as valid
        //Make sure to declare your named ranges exactly as declared in "Styles" but replacing any spaces with "_" in order for this code to run
        rangeStyle = row[2].replace(" ", "_"); 
        break
      }
    }
    
    //Looping through defined Named Ranges to identify and set drop-down list
    var namedRangeList = ss.getNamedRanges();
    for (namedRange of namedRangeList) {
      if (namedRange.getName() == rangeStyle) { //if the Range name defined in Styles is the same as Named Range name...
        var rangeSizes = namedRange.getRange();

        activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearContent().clearDataValidations(); //cleaning column D from the modified row
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rangeSizes).build(); //Instantiating DataValidation object with the range of data retrieved previously
        activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(validationRule); //Setting DataValidation object as value of column D from the modified row

      }
    }
  }
}
```

- `EDIT:` Make sure to declare your Named Ranges replacing spaces with "_" for this code to work on the new Sheet provided.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo this is really good. I thought I could simplify my request and adapt the solution to my actual sheet - but that's proving a bit difficult. Can you please take a look at this new sheet which resembles my actual sheet... hopefully your function won't need too many adjustments https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfs3fIj8pgMkmfySzbXUCqgXainG2o1rchLg4foVZeo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've edited my previous answer to adapt to the new Sheet. Don't forget to accept my answer if it works for you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Gustavo! I've accepted a different answer on this occasion but I appreciate your effort and adapting your script on my behalf. I'll keep the Google Sheet public and hopefully your code will help someone else in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get this with:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Products!A1:D, 4, 0), 
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(Sizes!A1:C,,9^9))), " ", "×", 1), "×"), 2, 0)))
```

but to turn it into dropdowns try:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution to my request and I'll keep this example online. I probably favour a Script solution as this method will be adding 40 helper columns to my sheet (I have many more sizes than my example).